# Using Nokogiri to scrape a value from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I wrote a simple script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=MYGN"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
name = doc.at_css("#yfi_rt_quote_summary h2").text
market_cap = doc.at_css("#yfs_j10_mygn").text
ebit = doc.at("//*[@id='yfncsumtab']/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/strong").text


puts "#{name} - #{market_cap} - #{ebit}"
```

The script grabs three values from Yahoo finance. The problem is that the `ebit` XPath returns nil. The way I got the XPath was using the Chrome developer tools and copy and pasting.

This is the page I'm trying to get the value from http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=MYGN and the actual value is `483,992` in the `total current assets` row.

Any help would be appreciated, especially if there is a way to get this value with CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri supports:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://au.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=MYGN"))
ebit = doc.at('strong:contains("Total Current Assets")').parent.next_sibling.text.gsub(/[^,\d]+/, '')

puts ebit
# >> 483,992
```

I'm using the `<strong>` tag as an place-marker with the `:contains` pseudo-class, then backing up to the containing `<td>`, moving to the next `<td>` and grabbing its text, then finally stripping the white-space using `gsub(/[^,\d]+/, '')` which removes everything that isn't a number or a comma.

Nokogiri supports a number of jQuery's JavaScript extensions, which is why `:contains` works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
doc.css("table.yfnc_tabledata1 tr[11] td[2]").text.tr(",","").to_i
#=> 483992
```

Or as a string

```
doc.css("table.yfnc_tabledata1 tr[11] td[2]").text.strip.gsub(/\u00A0/,"")
#=> "483,992"
```