# Parsing HTML - searching links - is it possible to search paragraph that a link is contained in?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing

I am parsing the links on wikipedia pages of actors, and trying to find links to films they appeared in.

I have a basic method that searchs the links and checks for the word `film` in the link. However many of the links to films do not actually contain this word.

However, within the paragraphs that the links are contained in, the word film appears , for example:

```
    <p>Dreyfuss's first film part was a small, uncredited role in 
<i><a href="/wiki/The_Graduate" title="The Graduate">The Graduate 

    // Paragraph goes on for a long time.
```

Here is the block from the method that checks all the links:

```
all_links = doca.search('//a[@href]')
    all_links.each do |link|
        link_info = link['href']
        if link_info.include?("(film)") && !(link_info.include?("Category:") || link_info.include?("php"))
            then out << link_info end
      end
    out.uniq.collect {|link| strip_out_name(link)}
```

Would there be a way of checking the previous text before the link but after the `<p>` tag for the word `film`, but being careful not to check other links (and also perhaps limited the search to 50 characters before the link)?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

[Click here, this is the main page that I am testing on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dreyfuss)

Comment: Here's a thought. Give it pretty side range for thinking a link is a film (something like the word film within 100 characters), and then scrape the films page to confirm that it is a film. Also, if all your trying to do is to get from Actor->Films, maybe you should try IMDB instead.

Comment: `.parent` will return the parent node so in this case the `<i>` tag so if they are all formatted the same way you could try `.parent.parent` which should return the `<p>` tag. if you post the page you are trying to parse I could test this.

Comment: @engineersmnky I posted the link 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dreyfuss`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to search for text inside a tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816840/128421 for an example.

But, I'd do it something similar to this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dreyfuss'))

table = doc.at('#Filmography').parent.next_element
films = table.search('tr')[1..-1].map{ |tr|
  tds = tr.search('td')
  year = tds.shift.text

  movie = tds.shift
  movie_url = movie.at('a')['href']
  movie_title = movie.at('a').text

  role = tds.shift.text

  {
    year: year,
    movie_url: movie_url,
    movie_title: movie_title,
    role: role
  }
}

films 
# => [{:year=>"1966",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Bewitched",
#      :movie_title=>"Bewitched",
#      :role=>"Rodney"},
#     {:year=>"1966",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Gidget_(TV_series)",
#      :movie_title=>"Gidget",
#      :role=>"Durf the Drag"},
#     {:year=>"1967",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Valley_of_the_Dolls_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Valley of the Dolls",
#      :role=>"Assistant stage manager"},
#     {:year=>"1967",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Graduate",
#      :movie_title=>"The Graduate",
#      :role=>"Boarding House Resident"},
#     {:year=>"1967",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Big_Valley",
#      :movie_title=>"The Big Valley",
#      :role=>"Lud Akley"},
#     {:year=>"1968",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Young_Runaways",
#      :movie_title=>"The Young Runaways",
#      :role=>"Terry"},
#     {:year=>"1969",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Hello_Down_There",
#      :movie_title=>"Hello Down There",
#      :role=>"Harold Webster"},
#     {:year=>"1970",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Mod_Squad",
#      :movie_title=>"The Mod Squad",
#      :role=>"Curtis Bell"},
#     {:year=>"1973",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/American_Graffiti",
#      :movie_title=>"American Graffiti",
#      :role=>"Curt Henderson"},
#     {:year=>"1973",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Dillinger_(1973_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Dillinger",
#      :role=>"Baby Face Nelson"},
#     {:year=>"1974",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Apprenticeship_of_Duddy_Kravitz_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz",
#      :role=>"Duddy"},
#     {:year=>"1974",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Second_Coming_of_Suzanne",
#      :movie_title=>"The Second Coming of Suzanne",
#      :role=>"Clavius"},
#     {:year=>"1975",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Inserts_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Inserts",
#      :role=>"The Boy Wonder"},
#     {:year=>"1975",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Jaws_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Jaws",
#      :role=>"Matt Hooper"},
#     {:year=>"1976",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Victory_at_Entebbe",
#      :movie_title=>"Victory at Entebbe",
#      :role=>"Colonel Yonatan 'Yonni' Netanyahu"},
#     {:year=>"1977",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind",
#      :movie_title=>"Close Encounters of the Third Kind",
#      :role=>"Roy Neary"},
#     {:year=>"1977",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Goodbye_Girl",
#      :movie_title=>"The Goodbye Girl",
#      :role=>"Elliott Garfield"},
#     {:year=>"1978",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Big_Fix",
#      :movie_title=>"The Big Fix",
#      :role=>"Moses Wine"},
#     {:year=>"1980",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Competition_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"The Competition",
#      :role=>"Paul Dietrich"},
#     {:year=>"1981",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Whose_Life_Is_It_Anyway%3F_(1981_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Whose Life Is It Anyway?",
#      :role=>"Ken Harrison"},
#     {:year=>"1984",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Buddy_System_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"The Buddy System",
#      :role=>"Joe"},
#     {:year=>"1986",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Down_and_Out_in_Beverly_Hills",
#      :movie_title=>"Down and Out in Beverly Hills",
#      :role=>"David 'Dave' Whiteman"},
#     {:year=>"1986",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Stand_by_Me_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Stand by Me",
#      :role=>"Narrator/Gordie LaChance (adult)"},
#     {:year=>"1987",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Tin_Men",
#      :movie_title=>"Tin Men",
#      :role=>"Bill 'BB' Babowsky"},
#     {:year=>"1987",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Stakeout_(1987_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Stakeout",
#      :role=>"Det. Chris Lecce"},
#     {:year=>"1987",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Nuts_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Nuts",
#      :role=>"Aaron Levinsky"},
#     {:year=>"1988",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Moon_Over_Parador",
#      :movie_title=>"Moon Over Parador",
#      :role=>"Jack Noah/President Alphonse Simms"},
#     {:year=>"1989",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Let_It_Ride_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Let It Ride",
#      :role=>"Jay Trotter"},
#     {:year=>"1989",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Always_(1989_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Always",
#      :role=>"Pete Sandich"},
#     {:year=>"1990",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Rosencrantz_%26_Guildenstern_Are_Dead_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Rosencrantz & Guildenstern Are Dead",
#      :role=>"The Player"},
#     {:year=>"1990",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Postcards_from_the_Edge_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Postcards from the Edge",
#      :role=>"Doctor Frankenthal"},
#     {:year=>"1991",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Once_Around",
#      :movie_title=>"Once Around",
#      :role=>"Sam Sharpe"},
#     {:year=>"1991",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Prisoner_of_Honor",
#      :movie_title=>"Prisoner of Honor",
#      :role=>"Col. Picquart"},
#     {:year=>"1991",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/What_About_Bob%3F",
#      :movie_title=>"What About Bob?",
#      :role=>"Dr. Leo Marvin"},
#     {:year=>"1993",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Lost_in_Yonkers_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Lost in Yonkers",
#      :role=>"Louie Kurnitz"},
#     {:year=>"1993",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Another_Stakeout",
#      :movie_title=>"Another Stakeout",
#      :role=>"Detective Chris Lecce"},
#     {:year=>"1994",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Silent_Fall",
#      :movie_title=>"Silent Fall",
#      :role=>"Dr. Jake Rainer"},
#     {:year=>"1995",
#      :movie_url=>
#       "/w/index.php?title=The_Last_Word_(1995_film)&action=edit&redlink=1",
#      :movie_title=>"The Last Word",
#      :role=>"Larry"},
#     {:year=>"1995",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_American_President_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"The American President",
#      :role=>"Senator Bob Rumson"},
#     {:year=>"1995",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Mr._Holland%27s_Opus",
#      :movie_title=>"Mr. Holland's Opus",
#      :role=>"Glenn Holland"},
#     {:year=>"1996",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/James_and_the_Giant_Peach_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"James and the Giant Peach",
#      :role=>"Centipede (voice)"},
#     {:year=>"1996",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Mad_Dog_Time",
#      :movie_title=>"Mad Dog Time",
#      :role=>"Vic"},
#     {:year=>"1997",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Night_Falls_on_Manhattan",
#      :movie_title=>"Night Falls on Manhattan",
#      :role=>"Sam Vigoda"},
#     {:year=>"1997",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Oliver_Twist_(1997_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Oliver Twist",
#      :role=>"Fagin"},
#     {:year=>"1998",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Krippendorf%27s_Tribe",
#      :movie_title=>"Krippendorf's Tribe",
#      :role=>"Prof. James Krippendorf"},
#     {:year=>"1999",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Lansky_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Lansky",
#      :role=>"Meyer Lansky"},
#     {:year=>"2000",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Crew_(2000_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"The Crew",
#      :role=>"Bobby Bartellemeo/Narrator"},
#     {:year=>"2000",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Fail_Safe_(2000_TV)",
#      :movie_title=>"Fail Safe",
#      :role=>"President of the United States"},
#     {:year=>"2001",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Old_Man_Who_Read_Love_Stories",
#      :movie_title=>"The Old Man Who Read Love Stories",
#      :role=>"Antonio Bolivar"},
#     {:year=>"2001",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Who_Is_Cletis_Tout%3F",
#      :movie_title=>"Who Is Cletis Tout?",
#      :role=>"Micah Donnelly"},
#     {:year=>"2001",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Education_of_Max_Bickford",
#      :movie_title=>"The Education of Max Bickford",
#      :role=>"Max Bickford"},
#     {:year=>"2001",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Day_Reagan_Was_Shot",
#      :movie_title=>"The Day Reagan Was Shot",
#      :role=>"Alexander Haig"},
#     {:year=>"2003",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Coast_to_Coast_(TV_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Coast to Coast",
#      :role=>"Barnaby Pierce"},
#     {:year=>"2004",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Silver_City_(2004_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Silver City",
#      :role=>"Chuck Raven"},
#     {:year=>"2006",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Poseidon_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Poseidon",
#      :role=>"Richard Nelson"},
#     {:year=>"2007",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Tin_Man_(TV_miniseries)",
#      :movie_title=>"Tin Man",
#      :role=>"Mystic Man"},
#     {:year=>"2007",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Ocean_of_Fear",
#      :movie_title=>"Ocean of Fear",
#      :role=>"Narrator"},
#     {:year=>"2008",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Signs_of_the_Time_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Signs of the Time",
#      :role=>"Narrator"},
#     {:year=>"2008",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/W._(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"W.",
#      :role=>"Dick Cheney"},
#     {:year=>"2008",
#      :movie_url=>"/w/index.php?title=America_Betrayed&action=edit&redlink=1",
#      :movie_title=>"America Betrayed",
#      :role=>"Narrator"},
#     {:year=>"2009",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/My_Life_in_Ruins",
#      :movie_title=>"My Life in Ruins",
#      :role=>"Irv"},
#     {:year=>"2009",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Leaves_of_Grass_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Leaves of Grass",
#      :role=>"Pug Rothbaum"},
#     {:year=>"2009",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/The_Lightkeepers",
#      :movie_title=>"The Lightkeepers",
#      :role=>"Seth"},
#     {:year=>"2010",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Piranha_3D",
#      :movie_title=>"Piranha 3D",
#      :role=>"Matthew Boyd"},
#     {:year=>"2010",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Weeds_(TV_series)",
#      :movie_title=>"Weeds",
#      :role=>"Warren Schiff"},
#     {:year=>"2010",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/RED_(film)",
#      :movie_title=>"RED",
#      :role=>"Alexander Dunning"},
#     {:year=>"2012",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Coma_(U.S._miniseries)",
#      :movie_title=>"Coma",
#      :role=>"Professor Hillside"},
#     {:year=>"2013",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Very_Good_Girls",
#      :movie_title=>"Very Good Girls",
#      :role=>"Danny, Gerry's father"},
#     {:year=>"2013",
#      :movie_url=>"/wiki/Paranoia_(2013_film)",
#      :movie_title=>"Paranoia",
#      :role=>"Francis Cassidy"}]
```

To explain what it's doing:

The "Filmology" table is a good source for the information; It's organized logically, so writing code to walk through it is easy.

```
doc.at('#Filmography').parent.next_element
```

finds that table using the `<h2>` heading just above it, then backs up and looks in the next tag, which is the table itself.

`table.search('tr')[1..-1]` finds the `<tr>` rows inside the table, skips the first, then iterates (using `map`) over the remaining ones.

`tds = tr.search('td')` finds the cells for the table. From that point on it's a matter of peeling that NodeSet apart like an array, by looking at the elements I want. The rest of the code should be pretty obvious. Once the individual parts are retrieved that are of interest they're bundled into a hash, which is returned as part of an array of hashes by `map`.

Comment: Even though it does not really answer the OP question this is by far the best way to parse the page for films

Comment: Thanks, need to do a big of alterations to make this fit in, but I like this..accepted

Comment: Well, they do have that table of information, which makes it *so* much easier than trying to pull information from random text. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @engineersmnky: "Even though it does not really answer the OP question this is by far the best way to parse the page for films". Yeah, it didn't answer the original question, but there's this thing called a "XY problem", where someone asks about question Y but they really want to know how to do X, which is the real problem. And, from experience having done a lot of page scraping for a living, it made sense that X was more useful, so I went with it. :-) "[What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) describes this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try parsing out the filmography section of the wikipedia article? It seems pretty standard across the few actors that I looked at, and it mentions whether or not it was a TV series so you could filter those out easily.

```
<tr>
    <td>1966</td>
    <td><i><a href="/wiki/Gidget_(TV_series)" title="Gidget (TV series)">Gidget</a></i></td>
    <td>Durf the Drag</td>
    <td>TV series 1 episode</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1967</td>
    <td><i><a href="/wiki/Valley_of_the_Dolls_(film)" title="Valley of the Dolls (film)">Valley of the Dolls</a></i></td>
    <td>Assistant stage manager</td>
    <td>Uncredited</td>
</tr>
```

Looks like you could pull nodes similar to this from the code and save all the info to do what you want with it. The first node  could be disregarded since "TV" appears multiple times in the different subnodes.

Hope this helps!

-Larry

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I have tested the code based on your actual request and come up with the following

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dreyfuss"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
all_links = doc.search("//a[@href]")
all_links.each do |link|
  p_text = link.ancestors("p").text
  link_index = p_text.index(link.text)
  unless link_index.nil?
     search_back = link_index > 50 ? link_index - 50 : 0
     p_text[search_back..link_index].downcase.include?("film") ? puts(link['href']) : nil
  end
end
```

Output

```
#=>/wiki/American_Graffiti
   /wiki/Jaws_(film)
   /wiki/Close_Encounters_of_the_Third_Kind
   /wiki/The_Graduate
   /wiki/The_Apprenticeship_of_Duddy_Kravitz_(film)
   /wiki/Down_And_Out_In_Beverly_Hills
   /wiki/Stakeout_(1987_film)
   /wiki/Stephen_King
   /wiki/The_Body_(novella)
   /wiki/Poseidon_(film)
   #cite_note-27
   /wiki/Jonathan_Tasini
```

This seems to satisfy the question you were asking but obviously needs to be modified to fit your needs.

## Edit

Added your request for running back on 50 characters in the paragraph the response is much shorter now but I am not sure that the results will be as useful as you'd like. This answers the question but does not capture exactly what you are hoping for e.g. the last 2 links are not to films but they are within 50 characters of the world film.

Comment: Useful - thanks - I only saw your edit after I accepted the other answer

Comment: That's fine the other answer is the best way to scrap the information you want my answer as geared more directly at your question.